# Prevent jquery colorbox closing on postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I am using jquery colorbox to call an external page from codebehind like this

```
 String URL = "Default.aspx"; 
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "openWindow", "$.colorbox({ href: '" + URL + "', closeButton: false, overlayClose: false });", true);
```

Below is html of Default.aspx

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Currently nothing is written on button click event, but as soon as I submit the button, the model window is getting closed. How do I prevent this? I want to be able to do certain calculation codebehind and then close the modelwindow if everything is fine.

Thanks,

Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button click submits the form and that executes a postback. If you need to perform server-side logic, you will need to get your button to call an ajax method to get the results from the server. Do do this, you either replace the OnClick with an OnClientClick method to call your ajax or you use a normal button and you wire up the on click event in javascript.

**HTML**

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="btn_Click" />
```

**Javascript**
Something along these lines:

```
function btn_Click(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //call your ajax here
    //update the page on ajax's success event
}
```

This should do it